# GET request returning 404 but service is running and receiving request

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, dropwizard

I'm working with an API I didn't build, and trying to debug it.  The path is below:

```
@UnitOfWork
@GET
@Path("uiOrder/search") 
...other code for the method...
```

when I hit it I'm getting a 404, along with most other paths, but strangely not all.  some give a 405.  The service itself is running, and the @Path("/") works as expected.

I know it's getting hit because I get the following in my console (using debug in intellij, other paths have similar results):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2016:11:51:36 +0000] "GET /uiOrder/search?worklist=fraud&totals=true HTTP/1.0" 404 1332 51 51
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2016:11:51:36 +0000] "GET /uiOrder/search?worklist=labels-requested&totals=true HTTP/1.0" 404 1332 51 51
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2016:11:51:36 +0000] "GET /uiOrder/search?worklist=labels-needed&totals=true HTTP/1.0" 404 1332 51 51
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Mar/2016:11:51:36 +0000] "GET /uiOrder/search?worklist=shipment-update&totals=true HTTP/1.0" 404 1332 52 52
```

what might cause the 404?  Where should I start looking?

Comment: I think you need to annotate `@Path("/uiOrder/search") ` and you also should annotate your query params `@QueryParam("worklist") String worklist ` and `@QueryParam("totals") Boolean totals `

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, found out another dev updated the service base url without telling me.